# This is Memory issue or not

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

When will i have running my app in simulator. xCode debug section shows cpu and memory section it will display some graph flow. but i don't know what is that. 
My question is,

1. what is that cpu and memory graph
2. when i running my app the memory increase towards when ever i navigate to any other viewcontroller and return back same or other viewcontroller etc.,  it always increase the memory size.

why it occurs. Is that any problem. if yes how to fix that and why i caused.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here below image i navigated to any other view controller. it is suddenly increase from above image memory size to below image memory size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that is a problem.  Looks like you are "holding onto" some objects that you don't need to.  You'll need to track it down using the static analyzer or instruments however.

Comment: i enabled static analyzer in build setting but it not show any information. which instrument type can use. because i never before used instrument functionality. help me how to i solve i enabled arc in my project @trojanfoe

Comment: @iDev Elaborate your question explaining as to what operations you do in your view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

Well from overall memory consumption it would seem as if you are handling some images or videos or other heavy content. Many make memory leaks handling those. To test if thats a real leak, you can do so:

Go to some page A (any page), from there go to some other page B, then back to A, back to B.. repeat that and if your memory is really getting high - you have a leak.

BUT bear in mind: These graphs show you how much resources your app use from your device, you SHOULD NOT use that to find leaks. Instead go to profiler, choose memory leaks and use that. If you are using ARC and cannot find any leaks, you can use "mark heap" button in allocations instrument to find memory build ups like this: Repeat the "page A page B" cycle and every time you are in page A, press "mark heap" button. You will now see generations which each show how much memory has increased from last generation. If it always keeps increasing same amount - double clicking generation will show you all the places that you have possible leaks.

Additional info: Easiest way to profile your app is to hold left mouse on "play" button in xcode until more buttons pop-up. Choose profile. When instruments appear - choose "Leaks".

From there - you should be able to see overall statistics of your app. I will not go in detail about profiler, because all the info is already available in the net. For example: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html